# Extract all text from a HTML page without losing context

Tags: php, multilingual, translate

For a translation program I am trying to get a 95% accurate text from a HTML file in order to translate the sentences and links.

For example:

```
<div><a href="stack">Overflow</a> <span>Texts <b>go</b> here</span></div>
```

Should give me 2 results to translate:

```
Overflow

Texts <b>go</b> here
```

Any suggestions or commercial packages available for this problem?

Comment: Gonna need a lot more information on your requirements, as the example you posted doesn't make sense. You appear to be treating your `span` tag as a block-level item, but they're not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but look at [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Specifically the "Extract Contents from HTML" tab under quick start on that front page (can't link directly, *sigh*). With that you can extract the text of a website without all those pesky tags.